# Highcharts Column with php

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax, highcharts

well im with a problem with a Highchart Graphic. This one -> http://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-basic

I have a database with a table call "Days" and "Works" and i want to put the days that i have in the "categories []" and the work in series[]; 
BUT
 i dont know how my JSON need to be, or the best way to do it is with a JS array

I tried this way:

```
    js_array = new Array(<?php echo implode(',', $array1); ?>);

 xAxis: {
            categories: js_array,
            crosshair: true
        },
```

or just `categories:<?php echo json_encode($array1);?>`

but dont succeed.

can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

I do this using asp.net (MVC5), but I think is the same idea for php, hope it helps.

```
<script>

    $(function () {
        var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
            chart: {
                type: 'column',
                renderTo: 'container'
            },
            title: {
                text: "Client's downloads"
            },
            subtitle: {
                text: 'Click the columns to view products.'
            },
            xAxis: {
                type: 'category'
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'Total downloads'
                }
            },
            legend: {
                enabled: false
            },
            plotOptions: {
                series: {
                    borderWidth: 0,
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: true
                    }
                }
            },
            tooltip: {
                headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:11px">{series.name}</span><br>',
                pointFormat: '<span style="color:{point.color}">{point.name}</span>: <b>{point.y:.2f}</b><br/>'
            },
            series: [{
                name: "Downloads",
                colorByPoint: true,
                data: [
                    @foreach (var item in Model)
                    {
                            <text>{</text>
                            <text>name: "</text> @item.Name <text>",</text>
                            <text>y: </text> @item.Downloads <text>,</text>
                            <text>drilldown: "</text>@item.Name<text>"},</text>
                    }
                ]
            }],
            drilldown: {
                series: [

                    @foreach (var item in Model)
                    {
                        <text>{</text>
                        <text>name: "</text>@item.Name<text>",</text>
                        <text>id: "</text>@item.Name<text>",</text>

                        <text>data: [</text>

                            foreach (var download in item.ProductDownloads)
                            {
                                <text>["</text> @download.Product <text>", </text> @download.Downloads <text>],</text>
                            }

                        <text>]</text>

                        <text>},</text>
                    }

                    ]
            }
        });
    });


</script>
```

Comment: My recommendation is do it using just javascript code, and then when it works add your php code.

Comment: Thanks man, it helps to undestand the logical concept of how to do it